# Sup/Inf Proof, real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded non-empty sets of real numbers with non-empty intersection.  Prove that $\sup \{A\cap B\} \leq\inf\{\sup A, \sup B\}$.

I know that $A\cap B$ is non-empty because both $A$ and $B$ are non-empty.  I also know that I must prove that something, we'll call it $X$, is less than or equal to the $\inf$ of the set by showing that it is the lower bound of the set.  However, I am unsure how to do.

I am using the following definition of infimum:
a) $s\geq w,\forall s\in S$ and
b) if $t$ is any lower bound of $S$, then $t\leq w$

Comment: What do you mean the inf of the set? It seems you are comparing $\sup(A \cap B)$ to the lesser of $\sup A$ and $\sup B$. If so, then note that $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ are both upper bounds for $A \cap B$. And $\sup(A \cap B)$.is the least upper bound for $A \cap B$. So then...
Also, $A$ and $B$ nonempty does not imply that $A \cap B$ is nonempty.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise good point.  But {sup A, sup B} is a set with two elements.  As a set this is clearly bounded below and inf{sup A, sup B} = min (sup A, sup B).

Answer (score 2):

I know that A ∩ B is non-empty because both A and B are non-empty.

NO.  You know it is non-empty because you were *told* it was non-empty.  A = odd integers and B = even integers are both non-empty but $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

You know $A \cap B$ is non-empty because you were told so.  Now you have to show that $A \cap B$ is bounded above.  Why?

Well A is bounded above (because we were told so) so if $a \in A$ then $a \le \sup A$.  So if $b \in A \cap B \subset A$ then $b \in A$ so $b \le \sup A$ so $A \cap B$ is bounded above by $\sup A$ and $\sup A\cap B \le \sup A $.

By the exact same argument $A \cap B$ is bounded above by $\sup B$ so $\sup A\cap B \le \sup B$.

So $\sup A\cap B \le \sup A$ and $\sup A\cap B \le \sup B$.  So $\sup A \le \min(\sup A, \sup B)$.

Post script:  I guess we also have to show for a *finite* set C, $\inf C = \min C$.  If C is finite $\min C$ exists and is well-defined.  (we just compare each element one after another).  For all $c \in C$ $ \min C \le C$ so $C$ is bounded below by $\min C$.  If $x > \min C$ then $\min C \in C$ and $\min C < x$ so $x$ is not a lower bound.  So $\min C$ is the greatest lower bound; $\min C = \inf C$.

But that only has to be true if C is finite.  If C is not finite $\min C$ need not exist.

So $\sup A\cap B \le \min (\sup A, \sup B) = \inf\{\sup A, \sup B\}$.

Post-post script:  If C is infinite and if $\min C$ exist (which it doesn't have to; $\min \{p \in \mathbb Q| p^2 > 2\}$ doesn't exist), then $\inf C = \min C$ by the same argument.  ($\min C \le c; \forall c \in C$ so $\min C$ is a lower bound, and $x > \min C \in C \implies x$ is not a lower bound.)  But if C is infinite, it doesn't follow that C is bounded below nor that $\min C$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see
$$
A\subset B\implies \sup A \leqslant\sup B
$$
In this case
\begin{align}
A\cap B\subset A \land A\cap B\subset B &\implies \sup (A\cap B) \leqslant\sup A\land \sup (A\cap B) \leqslant\sup B
\\
&\implies \sup (A\cap B) \leqslant\min(\sup A, \sup B)
\end{align}